Specific percentage for chance of a ritual going wrong
According to the Cult of the Lamb Fandom, the ritual Sinners Pride has a hidden detriment that isn’t mentioned in game (bolding mine):

Perform a Ritual at your Temple, causing the chosen follower to take
on the Sin of other followers. It will also accumulate sins from this
ritual. There is a risk of losing the Follower due to the number of
sin they are taking on.

How high is the risk of losing the follower (assuming it’s a percentage)? And what exactly happens if they’re lost?
As a side note, I have performed this ritual twice and nothing had happened, so either the chance is very low or I’m very lucky.

I don't know if this is a thing that actually happens in-game. Is there a secondary source for this other than Fandom/Wikia?

@Hoppeduppeanut No, this was the only source (but also the only place I looked).
